Decay of an excited spin 0 nucleus into the ground state with the creation of electron-positron pair
I am not sure how to write the amplitude, $M$, for this process. I assume that the nucleus should decay into a nucleus in the ground state and a longitudinal photon which in turn decays into an electron-positron pair (please, see the attached image). Therefore, my assumption is that
$$M = J^{\mu} \frac{-ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2} \bar{u}^s(k_1)(-ie\gamma^{\nu})v^{s'}(k_2)$$
where $J^{\mu}$ is the matrix element of electromagnetic current operator of the spin $0$ nucleus:
$$J^{\mu} = F(q^2)((p_1 + p_2)^{\mu} - q^{\mu}\frac{(p_1 + p_2)\cdot q}{q^2})$$
However, I am not sure if the expression for $J^{\mu}$ is correct and I also do not know if I need to sum over the electron and positron spins when calculating $M^2$.
